# Dynamic select options and save in xml file

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, sax

I have an application where in i got some check box, combo box etc. I need to save the selected data by a user in the form of an XML file at a specified location in my system

And i need to perform this using Java . I am relatively very new to XML handling in java
Any code snippets and links will be helpful ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the [Preferences API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/preferences/) ? It will take a lot of the effort out of this, albeit taking some control out of your hands too. Note that the [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html) class allows import/export of XML

> This class contains an export/import facility, allowing preferences to
>   be "exported" to an XML document, and XML documents representing
>   preferences to be "imported" back into the system. This facility may
>   be used to back up all or part of a preference tree, and subsequently
>   restore from the backup.

[Apache Commons Config](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) is another option since you can *explicitly* choose an XML backing store.